# How to copy data of first table to second table using Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I just want to copy data(Item and Price) of the first table to the second table and make increment in Quantity(Second table) when i click in the First Table ( Item). I am working on Angular 9

**First Table**:

```
Code | Item  | Price | Unit  |
1    | Mouse | 500   | Piece |
2    | Wire  | 100   | Piece |
```

**Second Table**:

```
Item | Quantity| Price | 
1    | 2       | 1000  | 
2    | 1       | 100   |
```

I did a lot to work with it but I could not get any required output.
It is possible to solve using **javaScript/Js/jquery**

```html
<table class="table table-hover" id="firstTable">
    <thead class="table-primary">
        <tr>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Unit</td>
            <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of itemList;" id="moveMeIntoMain"
            style="cursor:pointer">
            <td>{{data.itemCode}}</td>
            <td>{{data.itemName}}</td>
            <td><span>{{data.unitId}}</span>{{data.name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.retailRate}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<table class="table table-hover" id="secondTable">
    <thead class="">
        <tr class="table-primary">
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>    
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Js

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        var items = [];
        $("#firstTable tr").on("click", function () {
            var newTr = $(this).closest("tr").clone();
            
            $(newButtonHTML).children("button").click(function (e) {
            });
            $(newTr).children("td:last").html("");
            items.push(newTr);
            newTr.appendTo($("#secondTable"));
        });
    })
```

Comment: How did you contruct first table? using angular *ngFor?

Comment: yeah!! m using *ngFor..

Comment: Now i am working on it. I will inform you soon as possible :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try in Angular way ;). Just add click handler to the each row and send row data

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vswlnf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Template file**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Unit</th>
  </thead>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of firstTableData" (click)="updateSecondTable(data)">
    <td>{{ data.Code }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.Item }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.Price }}</td>
    <td>{{ data.Unit }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table *ngIf="secondTableData.length">
  <thead>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let newdata of secondTableData">
      <td>{{ newdata.Item }}</td>
      <td>{{ newdata.Quantity }}</td>
      <td>{{ newdata.Price }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And in the **typescript file**

- Declare a empty `secondTableData` array
- And have a method, which firstly checks for the item existence in the second table array. If item already exists, then simply update `quantity` and `price`
- If item doesn't exist, just push the item with required columns to the second table array

**Component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  firstTableData = [{
      Code: 1,
      Item: 'Mouse',
      Price: 500,
      Unit: 'Piece'
    },
    {
      Code: 2,
      Item: 'Wire',
      Price: 100,
      Unit: 'Piece'
    },
    {
      Code: 3,
      Item: 'Some Item',
      Price: 300,
      Unit: 'Some Unit'
    }
  ];
  secondTableData = [];

  updateSecondTable(data) {
    let foundItem = this.secondTableData.find((item) => item.Item === data.Item);
    if (foundItem) {
      foundItem.Quantity += 1;
      foundItem.Price += data.Price;
      return;
    }
    this.secondTableData.push({
      Item: data.Item,
      Quantity: 1,
      Price: data.Price,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Its working fine. Thank you so much. Let me add one more question.. How can I remove quantity and decrease price one by one after clicking Minus button in Action column? :-)

Comment: @Dany it would be better having this one as seperate question ;)